# How can a function manipulate parameters passed via another function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

Sorry, first attempt at explaining this question was poor.  Trying to learn Javascript and a question from a code problem (codewars) has me stumped. It states, write a function that takes another function as a parameter and caches results so that if the same parameters are sent then the return is pulled from the cache and the actual function is not invoked again.  For example:

```
var x = function(a, b) { a * b };
var cachedFunction = cache(x);

cachedFunction(4, 5); // function x should be executed
cachedFunction(4, 5); // function x should not be invoked again, instead the cached result should be returned
cachedFunction(4, 6); // should be executed, because the method wasn't invoked before with these arguments
```

I am not sure how to access the arguments sent via cachedFunction.  The goal is to write cache so that it can handle a function x with any number of arguments.

Comment: You're not actually passing `x`, `5` and `4` to the `cache` function. You're passing 5 and 4 to the `x` function, receiving a result, and then passing _that_ to `cache`. (for what it's worth)

Comment: You can't.  Your `cache` function is being called with a value of `20` (the *result* of `x(5,4)`), it has no idea about what values were passed to `x` or that `x` was ever called.  Also, what does your `cache` function do?  Are you *supposed* to be passing it a function?  Because currently, you are not.

Comment: Sorry, my first attempt at understanding the problem and wording the question was poor.  I've rewritten it.  not sure if the correct etiquette was to scrap the original altogether and rewrite or to make such a large edit.  My apologies if I should have done the former.

Comment: Your edit invalidated all given answers since your question is now a very different one. Better revert your edit and ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is not possible.

The expression `x(5, 4)` is evaluated before the `cache()` function is even called. It's not receiving a function. It's receiving the value `20`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `cache` only has access to the return value of `x`. It can't know anything about how this return value was computed (i. e. by calling `x` with parameters `5, 4`).

You would need to separately pass the function and its parameters to the `cache` function, e. g. as follows:

```js
function cache(func, ...params) {
  // Todo: do something with params  
  return func(...params);
}

function x(a, b){
  return a * b;
}

console.log(cache(x, 5, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can return a table like this:

```
function x(a,b){
    return [a, b, a*b];
}
```

after that you can get the params like this:

```
var result=x(values1,value2);
console.log(result[0]);// a == value1
console.log(result[1]);// b == value2
console.log(result[2]);// a*b == value1*value2
```